# Error Object reference not set to instance of object when passing cookie to API

Tags: c#, cookies

I am attempting to pass a cookie to an API to consume one of its services. However, it comes up with this error, so matter how I attempt to do so. Here is the line of code where this occurs:

```
_service.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", sessionID) { Domain = "webservices.24sevenoffice.com" });
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? SessionID is NOT null, and the other values are explicitly given so it's quite confusing.

Comment: The only things in that line that looks like they could be `null` and causing that error are `_service` or `CookieContainer` - are they definitely set to something?  Assuming that the error is thrown _by that specific line_ and not within the `Add` method or `Cookie` constructor.

Comment: Either way, the techniques described in the answers to [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) should help you track down the issue.

Comment: _service must be defined like _service = new ...(); before this line because you are trying to add cookieContainer to service. this is the only possible thing i can see from here depending on your error.

Comment: if there is List of CookieContainer inside service you must set List inside constructor too. like `List<CookieContainer> CookieContainer= new List<CookieContainer>`inside Constructor.how ever i dont know what is the type of _service